# Find and replace URLs in CSS in Python?

Tags: python, css, parsing, css-parsing

I am writing a Web site archiving bot. I have it set up to find URLs in HTML and rewrite them to point to the archive. Is there a way to do this in CSS? I basically need to extract all the URLs, process them with a function, and insert new ones. They're all in `url(...)` wrappers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. I haven't tried anything for CSS yet.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site where you can ask questions about issues with your code, algorithm or programming tool usage. This of cause means you need to have code, an algorithm or a tool you are using.

Comment: Okay. Is there a site for asking "what is the best way to do this"?

Comment: The rules here are strict, asking for off-site resources like websites is also not allowed.

Comment: @KlausD. Okay. Should I delete the question?

Comment: It would be best if you research and try for yourself and ask a question with some code if you get stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.